# nginx deny access to root and all subfolders

Tags: nginx, openresty

I'm using:

```
location / {
# IPv6 allow
allow IPv6 address 1;
allow IPv6 address 2;
# IPv4 allow
allow IPv4 address 1;
allow IPv4 address 2;
# deny
deny all;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

This does have the expected effect (blocking all except allowed IPs) but only for the root "/".

If an IP that is not allowed goes to https://www.example.com it is blocked (403 error) but if it goes to https://www.example.com/subfolder it would be allowed.

I would like to extend this match to disallow access to all subfolders and I would like to do that without naming those subfolders (as there are thousands :) ).

Anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: Move the allow/deny statements up one level into the surrounding block, which is the `server` block, and controls access to all locations within the server.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like it did the trick :)